# Can I write to a new file, then read from that file within the same C program?

Tags: c, file-io

```
FILE *new = fopen("new.out", "w+"); // creates a new file that didnt exist before
char finput[50];

fprintf(new, "hello\nworld\n");

while(fgets(finput, 51, new) != NULL)
{ /*never reaches this point*/ }
```

What am I doing wrong? If I write to a file that doesn't already exist, is it possible to read from that file later on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should `rewind` or `fseek` before reading again. And please, don't call a variable `new` (because that is a C++ keyword).

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something to change the mode between write and read. `fseek` is a possibility.

> On streams open for update (read+write), a call to fseek allows to switch between reading and writing.

`fsetpos` and `rewind` work as well.

Answer (score 1):

You've opened the file in `w+` mode, which is read/write in append mode. After your fprintf() command, the file pointer is at the END of the file, meaning there's nothing to read but EOF. You have to `fseek()` to another point in the file, or `rewind()` to the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/). They advice you to check `errno` on error. You can use

```
perror("Fgets failed");
```

to print full error message.

To the problem: you need to call `fseek` when changing from write to read (always).

```
fseek(new, 0, SEEK_SET);
```

rewinds the file.